# Pandas: Find consecutive items in a column separated by 50 units

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, that can be short or long that looks like this

```
          alt    start      end
0  borderline  6017254  6017304
1  borderline  6017304  6017354
2  borderline  6017354  6017404
3  duplicated  6018212  6018262
4  borderline  6018262  6018312
5  borderline  6018312  6018362
```

and I need to find "consecutive" items in the `start` and `end` columns. I can groupby `alt` and get the rows for each `alt` type, but the consecutive items in `start` and `end` are separated by 50 units, either on a columns or rows. In summary what I want to obtain is

```
          alt    start      end
0  borderline  6017254  6017404
1  duplicated  6018212  6018262
2  borderline  6018262  6018362
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you get this output?

Comment: I want to find regions of 50 units that are consecutive. Region 1 would start on `6017254-6017304` and end on `6017354-6017404` and they are members of the `borderline` "class". All these rows are in a bigger data frame and I am using Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `shift`  and `groupby`

```
df.groupby([df.alt,(df.start.shift(-1)==df.end).shift().ne(True).cumsum()],sort=False).agg({'alt':'first','start':'first','end':'last'})
Out[433]: 
                     alt    start      end
alt                                       
borderline 1  borderline  6017254  6017404
duplicated 2  duplicated  6018212  6018262
borderline 2  borderline  6018262  6018362
```

More info about the shift , It will create the group key , by using start to match the previous end , if matched , it will belong to the same group ,  if not , it will return False, then after `cumsum` we count then in the next group

```
(df.start.shift(-1)==df.end).shift().ne(True).cumsum()

Out[434]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
dtype: int32
```

Comment: In general might need to sort first if `start` isn't ordered. Definitely going to use this in a similar problem I tackled :D